# In Jetbrains, how can I see the file paths when I use "Show Usages"?

Tags: shortcuts, ide, intellisense, rubymine

I often will want to see where a class, object, variable etc is used throughout a project.
[Jetbrain lets you do this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/find-highlight-usages.html) but when it shows you the usages, it will display the file name but it does not include the **path** to that file.

[rubymine show usages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIVJ5.png)

Does anyone know how to get paths showing in this window?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment this is not implemented, so please add your vote and follow the corresponding issue on the platform tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-208638